# Build dict A based on values of dict B python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that look something of the sort:

```
mode1=1,2,3,4

mode2=5,3,6,8

mode3=a,t,5,6
etc.

**END MODES**

group1=mod1,mode2

group2=group1,mode3
etc.

**END_GROUPS**
```

I built a dictionary  modes where the keys are the modes.
code looks something like this:

```
for line in mode_def_file:
    if "**END_MODES**" in line:
        break
    k, v = line.strip().split('=')
    modes_dict[k] = v.split(',')
```

Now to build group dict since values are keys of group_dict or modes_dict
i would like `group_dict[group2] = [1,2,3,4,5,3,6,8,a,t,5,6]`.
I can think of the straightforward approach but is there a quick clean and efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a great potential of using one-liners here but the cleanest and the most maintainable I can think of is as follows. It should be pretty close to the most-efficient, as you'll have to do a second check anyway to see if the `value` you got can be expanded again (you know, in case `'group1'`). It's probably not different than your straightforward solution anyway.

```
def generate(dictionary, query):
    result = []

    queryItems = query.split(',')

    # Traverse dictionary keys
    for i in queryItems:
        # Traverse dictionary values
        for j in dictionary[i].split(','):
            # If the value exists as a key in the dictionary expand it, if not take it as-is
            result.extend(dictionary[j].split(',') if j in dictionary else j)

    return result

dict = { 'mode1':'1,2,3,4', 'mode2':'5,3,6,8', 'group1':'mode1,mode2' }

print(generate(dict, 'mode1,mode2,group1'))
```